# How to read file bytes in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I read a byte from a file, and put it into a byte array without converting the byte to an integer?

Comment: The answer in short: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your file name");
byte[] bytes = new byte[100]; // replace 100 with the desired size, of course
int offset = 0;               // which element to stuff the byte into  

fis.read(bytes, offset, 1);   // the 1 is how many bytes to read
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    byte ch;
    try {
      is = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("fileName.dat"));
      while (true) { 
        ch = is.readByte();
   // put here in any byte array ...
        System.out.flush();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose we must set the bounds of the byte array, right? What do you suggest to instantiate byte array without knowing its count? Vector or ArrayList would be so high level solution?

Comment: Yups, I would suggest use some buffer , ByteBuffer and then finally push that in whatever object you want you